# sharing variables between classes

Tags: java, class, variables, share

I have a problem that sounds stupid but don't know why it does not work. I have 2 classes, Directory and Map, and inside the Directory class there is a local String variable that takes the name of the current folder of the directory and want to put it inside a rectangle in the Map class that displays the graphics. After putting the variable into the Map class, the problem is that the string is empty.

Here is the code :

```
public class Directory
{
    public static File directory;   // the directory that we want to use
    public static String dirName = directory.getName();
    public String test = "test";

    public Directory(File directory)
    {
        files = directory.listFiles();
    }    
}

public class Test extends JComponent
{
    Directory dir = new Directory(null);
    public Test()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
        g.drawString(dir.tigka, 10, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that Map.folderName is null or empty?  Where do you check it?

Comment: This is the problem : 
java.lang.NullPointerException: String is null

Comment: This can't be the real code - you are calling `new Directory(null)` but the `Directory` class only has a no-arg constructor. Can you post the real code and mark the line where the NullPointerException is thrown? Make sure you post a SSCCE (see http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This is still not SSCCE - what does 'files' refer to in the Directory constructor? But at least we can see a problem now. You are passing `null` to the constructor then trying to call `listFiles` on that null reference, hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: The latest code update contains a Directory class, with a "public static" value, "String dirName". The use of "public static" makes it a class variable, not an instance variable. Problem with that is you're setting it's value to the value of an instance variable, which doesn't exist at the time that the class is loaded. I'm really confused as to what you're trying to accomplish here. There's a very weird combination of class and instance variables. Making it "public static" will definitely share it among classes, but you're initializing it very strangely.

Comment: Also, what happened to the Map class?

Comment: This may not be a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instantiated a Directory object with (null), and then used that instance to set the String variable. Makes perfect sense that the null passes though.

```
Directory dir = new Directory(null);
String folderName = dir.folderName;
```

Comment: i think that the constructor does not have to do with the variable. In the main class where i call it and use it, i use the path of the File that is required. Is there any other way to call it without using these two code lines?

Comment: In the code sample above, are you expecting "String folderName = dir.folderName;" to set "String foldername = ..." to "test" - since that's what in the Directory constructor? If your real code is different than the sample code, please post the real code. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: there will be a problem if i post all of the code because it is more than a hundred lines. My question is how can i use a local variable from the class Dog to the class Cat. Let's forget about the rest code. The first thing we want is the variable to be public. After that?

Comment: @Eristikos: Try to cut down your code to the smallest amount that actually shows the problem. Make sure it compiles and gives you the same error you are seeing. What you have posted *looks* fine, but clearly something else is going on, otherwise you wouldn't be having the problem you describe.

Comment: @Cameron: _What you have posted looks fine_ ... I disagree.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner is correct; without and [sscce](http://sscce.org) it's almost impossible to offer useful help.

Comment: I've up-voted trashgod's answer. I think part of the issue is an overall structural one. Public instance variables, while valid, don't really follow good object-oriented design, in this case. Try using getter and setter methods.

Do you have previous programming experience in another language that isn't object oriented by chance (where this method of coding is more common)?

Comment: @Sthupahsmaht: I meant fine in the sense that it shouldn't be throwing a NPE...it would be better if it compiled. Although there is new code there now so maybe that's fixed.

Comment: problem solved. Normalocity and everyone thank you a lot. The problem after some changes in the code still was the null inside the Directory constructor, but still i do not know why it required that...

Comment: Also after that, i tried to delete the Directory dir = new Directory(new File("url") and putting the string inside the paintComponent as Directory.tigka and it also worked as well. So i think that i was right about the non usage of the this code line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new solution I discovered (I'm a beginner) for maintaining one central, dynamic variable location for all classes in an application, regardless of how many times the same variables are used or where or when they are used. It sounds like it might apply to a solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861704/solution-for-sharing-variables-between-classes?noredirect=1#comment26078064_17861704

Answer (score -1):

weird question and hard to evaluate the answers, as the target is changing so much .. nevertheless, can't resist throwing in my couple of cents (Euro!) as well because I think the reason for the NPE is not yet spotted

The code I'm referring to is (in case it's changing while I'm writing)

```
public /* static */ class Directory
{
    public static File directory;   // the directory that we want to use
    public static String dirName = directory.getName();
    public String test = "test";

    public Directory(File directory)
    {
        files = directory.listFiles();
    }    
}
```

instantiating with a null file looks like the culprit ... but is never reached: the first NPE thrown comes from the static initialization of dirName which accesses the static field directory which is .. well, null

Edit (as of @Eristikos comment): removed the static class modifier to stay in synch with the original example.

Comment: are you sure that making a class static is valid? the compiler in netbeans does not accept it.

Comment: @Eristikos - yes, if it's a nested class. Needed only for a quick test, to allow the static fields ;-) Will edit, to keep it in line with the original, thanks for the heads-up!